# Having a issue with the .txt giving a not defined error when running program in python

Tags: python

When running the program in python, the first two parts of it work properly. I'm able to define where I want the numbers to go and how many I want there to be but I always get a "NameERROR".

```
import random

def main():
#Local variables
filename = open('TestFile.txt', 'w')
numberOfRandoms = 0
randomNumber = 0

#Get the file name as input from the user
filename = input('Enter the name of the file to '\
             'which results should be written: ')

#Get the number of items to write to the file
numberOfRandoms = int(input('Enter the number of '\
                            'random numbers to be written to the file: '))
#Open the output file
outputFile = open(TestFile.txt, 'w')
#Write a specified number of random numbers to the file
for counter in range (numberOfRandoms):

    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
    outputFile.write(str(randomNumber) + '\n')
#Closing the file
outputFile.close()
print(numberOfRandoms, 'numbers were written to', TestFile.txt)
main()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. Its got a more detailed description of the error and the failing line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget the quotes for your file name in the 3rd and the 4th parts.

`outputFile = open('TestFile.txt', 'w')`.

and

`print(numberOfRandoms, 'numbers were written to', 'TestFile.txt')`.

Comment: I also overlooked that I did define the .txt in the 3rd line. Went back and changed all the "TestFile.txt" to "Filename" and got the program to work!! Thanks for your help.